# How can I dynamically create multiple divs and give them each a specific background image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have 6 div's each is going to contain a different background image.

Instead of me writing out:

```
%div.container
  %div.projects
    =link_to('#') do
      %div.item
      /end div.item
    /end link_to()

    =link_to('#') do
      %div.item
      /end div.item
    /end link_to()

    =link_to('#') do
      %div.item
      /end div.item
    /end link_to()

    =link_to('#') do
      %div.item
      /end div.item
    /end link_to()

    =link_to('#') do
      %div.item
      /end div.item
    /end link_to()

    =link_to('#') do
      %div.item
      /end div.item
    /end link_to()
  /end div.projects
/end div.container
```

and changing the class of each div to say; item-1, item-2...and so on, how can I create the divs dynamically and still manage to populate them with their appropriate background image?

I am looking for a totally DRY approach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not postive about ruby, but could you use a for loop? and use the index to increase the number on the class of the div?

Comment: What does this have to do with Sass or JavaScript?

Comment: Are the images in sequence? Do you have an array with there names? Please elaborate

Answer (score 1):

You could simply loop through a collection of objects containing the information you need, use `image-url` to set the `background-image` property of each div:

```
%div.projects
  - projects.each do |project|
    = link_to(project.link) do
        %div{ style: "background-url: #{image-url(project.background_image)}" } = a
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a [loop](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/loop):

```
- 1..6.times.each do
  = link_to('#') do
      %div.item
```

If you wanted to loop through your objects specifically, you'd be best using something like this:

```
- projects.each do |project|
  = link_to project.name, project
```